# Rails 3.1. Create one user in console with secure password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create one user (admin) and I want to use console (without user registration model). I use solution from RailsCasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1).
But I have one problem: when I do User.create(..., :password => "pass") in console my password stored in database without encription (like "pass"). And I can't login with my data.

How can I create user from console? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Straight from the Rails API

```
# Schema: User(name:string, password_digest:string)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end

user = User.new(:name => "david", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "nomatch")
user.save                                                      # => false, password required
user.password = "mUc3m00RsqyRe"
user.save                                                      # => false, confirmation doesn't match
user.password_confirmation = "mUc3m00RsqyRe"
user.save                                                      # => true
user.authenticate("notright")                                  # => false
user.authenticate("mUc3m00RsqyRe")                             # => user
```

You need to include `:password_confirmation => "pass` in your hash!

Right, so taking a look at `has_secure_password` you want to perform `BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password)` to obtain it.  You'll need the `bcrypt-ruby` gem to do the above.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about BCrypt, it works well without password confirmation too :)